# .Focus() is not working using jquery or javascript in JQUERY MOBILE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Trigger keyboard in input field (HTML / Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858545/iphone-trigger-keyboard-in-input-field-html-javascript)

I am working on jquery mobile site. I want to give focus to text field using javascript or jquery so it will popup keyboard. I have tried `.focus(), .select()` and `.trigger('focus')` but it's not working.
--HTML--

```
<input id='txt' type='search' value='' />
```

--JQUERY--

```
$('#txt').focus();  

$('#txt').select();

$('#txt').focus();
```

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/3aGbr/

Comment: Where do you run this code, in the page head? Try moving it to the bottom of the page, just before you close the body tag, or put it in a DOM-ready callback. It might be that the code is run before the element actually is in the DOM.

Comment: which mobile device are you trying this on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Trigger keyboard in input field (HTML / Javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858545/iphone-trigger-keyboard-in-input-field-html-javascript) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609765/manually-triggering-the-iphone-ipad-ipod-keyboard-from-javascript There may not be a solution to this.

Comment: try this document.getElementById('txt').focus();

Comment: You should look through your code and make sure you're not doing a .blur() anywhere else. It would be helpful if you could add more of your source code so we could find something like that.

Comment: Can you re-word your question? `.focus()` IS working, it just isn't displaying the iphone's keyboard.

Comment: ipad's and iphone's webkit is the new IE6

Comment: If you edit the question can you please leave the "duplicate link" text in place.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Not sure if you meant jquery mobile or a mobile jquery site, but if you are indeed using **jquery mobile, see below**:

A few things since you note above that you're using [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html#):

> **Use $(document).on('pageinit'), not $(document).ready():**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Also, you may need to insert your `.focus` code inside an event, such as the `pagecreate` event:

> Triggered when the page has been created in the DOM (via ajax or
>   other) but before all widgets have had an opportunity to enhance the
>   contained markup. This event is most useful for user's wishing to
>   create their own custom widgets for child markup enhancement as the
>   jquery mobile widgets do.

See more events on the documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html#).

**If you're just using regular [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**, then you may need to wrap your code within the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`. This helps ensure that the DOM is loaded and allows your jQuery selector `$("#txt")` to find the element on the page. If the DOM hasn't loaded yet when your JavaScript is ran, the `input` will not be found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I'm using jquery mobile.And my code is in pageshow event so the .focus() will execute every time.

Comment: Is there any way you can update your question with the `pageshow` function that contains your `focus` call? That way I can take a look and see if I notice anything. Thanks

Comment: I found that it's actually impossible to focus in textbox using programming. it's usability issue..

Answer (score 0):

It should be working but since it's not, I would try something not so normal like .click(). Have you tried it? It should work.

Comment: i tried that also but it's not working...:(